# public void implementation does not work in fragment

Tags: android

I am running an **AsyncTask** in main activity and result of that is a string vector. I want to use this vector to change a list view in the fragment. I use an interface (Asyncresponce) to get the vector by  public void (processFinish) and then I implemented Asyncresponce in fragment and use it to clear and fill the Array adapter but public void does not work I use a logging statement to understand if this is running but I don't see it on device monitor.

I do not know what is the problem. Important parts of **main activity** and **asynctask**:

```
AsyncResponse myasync = new AsyncResponse() {
  public void processFinish(String output[]) {

  }
};

MainActivity.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask =  new MainActivity.FetchWeatherTask(myasync);
//MainActivity.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask =  new MainActivity.FetchWeatherTask();
weatherTask.execute("232931","82da4ddd2e8380be6dea06b177926b2d");
```

on post execute where I pass string vector on processFinish:

```
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "on post execute:+:  "+ resultStrs[1]);
delegate.processFinish(resultStrs);
```

and fragment:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment
implements MainActivity.AsyncResponse {
  public String[] weatherdata = new String[5];
  public ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
  public final String LOG_TAG_fragmet    =MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

  @Override
  public void  processFinish(String output[]) {
    if (output!= null){
      Log.v(LOG_TAG_fragmet, "this is from fragment="+ output[1]);
      mForecastAdapter.clear();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass your `MainActivityFragment` instance as the argument to the call `new MainActivity.FetchWeatherTask(myasync);`

The instance of `AsyncResponse` you are passing has an empty implementation for `processFinish(Object[])`, so you're not actually calling back to `MainActivityFragment`

Something like this maybe:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment
implements MainActivity.AsyncResponse {
public String[] weatherdata = new String[5];
public ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
public final String LOG_TAG_fragmet    =MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void  processFinish(String output[]) {

    if (output!= null){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG_fragmet, "this is from fragment="+ output[1]);
        mForecastAdapter.clear();
    }
}

public void someMethod() {
   MainActivity.FetchWeatherTask weatherTask =  new  MainActivity.FetchWeatherTask(this);
   weatherTask.execute("232931","82da4ddd2e8380be6dea06b177926b2d");
}
```

Comment: yes this works however i put it on Oncreateview. thanks a lot